# phonegap build include git non npm plugin

Tags: android, plugins, adobe

How do I include a plugin from git into the build of a phonegap build zip file?
The plugin specification in the config.xml file is

```
<plugin name="com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser" spec="~1.0.0" 
src="https://github.com/ourcodeworld/cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser.git" />
```

The project runs on Android as a Cordova app normally.  In PhoneGap Build I get an error message.
The specific error is:

```
 Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: 
com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser@~1.0.0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill in "spec" with the git plugin URL:

```
 <plugin   name="com.ourcodeworld.plugins.Filebrowser" 
           spec="https://github.com/ourcodeworld/cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser.git" />
```

The "src" is not needed.  The "name" is required by Visual Studio Cordova. PhoneGap Build will pull the plugin from git.  The documentation is here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/#plugin-source